# Creating a Workbook with a custom name without saving it to disk

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a Workbook with a custom name without saving it to disk? I want to avoid the default "Workbook x" names but I don't want to require the user to save the workbook. If I save it automatically in some temporary, the user won't get the "Save As..." dialog if he clicks on "Save", which may be confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply create the workbook and don't save it so when the user tries to save it, the user will get a "Save As" Prompt. And if the user tries to close it, then the user will get a prompt whether the users want to save (*Again a Save As dialog*) the file before closing. Now the appearance of this prompt will depend on the fact that you have made some changes to the newly created workbook.

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
End Sub
```

By default the workbook will be named as "Book*" but that really shouldn't matter as the user will get a chance to do do a "Save As"

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > By pressing Ctrl + S. It would show the Save As... dialog just as if the workbook had never been saved.

Though I mentioned that there is only one way that I can think of but while working on the code, I came up with 2 options :)

**WAY 1**

a) Create a new workbook

b) Save it as say, JAN 2012.XLSM, to user's Temp directory

c) Change the file properties to Readonly

d) Now when the user presses CTRL+S, Excel will prompt a Save As

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    With wb
        .SaveAs Filename:=TempPath & "JAN 2012.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

       '.SaveAs Filename:=TempPath & "JAN 2012.xlsx" _
       , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly, WritePassword:="admin"
    End With
End Sub

Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

**WAY 2 (Complicated way of doing it)**

a) Create a new workbook

b) Save it as say, JAN 2012.XLSM, to user's Temp directory

c) Inject a code to disable Ctrl + S and only allow Save As

Comment: Siddarth, I want to name the Workbooks differently than "Book x". My macro creates a few workbooks and having them named "Workbook 1", "Workbook 2" is confusing for the user. I want the workbooks to be named "JAN 2012", "FEB 2012" etc... and let the user decide if and where they want to save them.

Comment: And how would the user save the workbook? By pressing Ctrl + S / Excel menu or via the code?

Comment: By pressing Ctrl + S. It would show the Save As... dialog just as if the workbook had never been saved.

Comment: In that case I can think of only one solution. Gimme 15 mins. I will post the code :)

Comment: Why not save it in the temporary place and on the first save event call the saveas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Application Events** to manage creating and saving workbooks.

See [Application Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) from CPearson's site for more info.

My suggestion: create an Addin with an Application Event handler to manage new workbooks:

In the addin `ThisWorkbook` module (or use a class module as described by Pearson), incluse this code

```
Option Explicit

' Establish object to handle events
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

' Handle new workbook 
Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "New Book..."
    Wb.SaveAs "Your Path and File Name Here"
End Sub

' Intercept save event
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "Saving " & Wb.Name

End Sub
```